# Monitoring several thousands of directories for changes using Java

Tags: java, apache-commons

I have a requirement where I have to monitor several thousands for directories (that may also be on a remote share). Is there a way we could do this using Apache Commons FileAlterationMionitor? Is this even feasiable (looking at the CPU and memory usage - CPU usage is a bigger concern for us) to do something like this?